# Cannot resume from WP_Query loop

Tags: wordpress

With WordPress 4.9.8, I am trying to make a template for Page with custom `WP_Query` loop to get titles and authors of related posts.

The code below can show the titles and the authors in related posts but fails to resume to mail loop.

When I apply this template, `the_content()` and `wp_link_pages()` after WP_Query is not displayed.  If I move them before `WP_Query`, they are  displayed.

```php
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="entry-content">

    <!-- ▼WP_Query part-->
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'works',
        'posts_per_page' => 99,
        'meta_key' => 'nombre',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'Meta_query' => array(
                array(
                        'key' => 'mag',
                    'value' => the_post(),
                    'compare' => 'IN',
                ),
        ),
    ); ?>

    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if($my_query->have_posts()):?>
    <section>
        <h2>related posts</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                <li>
                    <span><?php the_title().' '.the_author(); ?></span>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <!-- ▲WP_Query part-->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . 'Pages:', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

I would like to know how I can display `the_content` after `WP_Query`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the content of the *page* after looping through the posts, you have to add another complete loop for fetching the page's content. In your code, you are resetting the postdata at the end of the post loop, so there is no active loop anymore, but `the_content()` always has to be *inside*  a loop - just add the default loop for the page once more.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will think about it.